# Android - How to deal with out of memory issues when loading multiple images?

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap

I am building an app where users can make x amount of steps(not limited). Each step has an image and some text. See the image below

[image]

Everytime the user pressed "next step" they can upload a new picture, either from the camera or by picking an existing one. Problem is, i get an OutOfMemory exception if i create a lot of steps. I'm using picasso to load the images into the imageview, but i keep getting out of memory if i keep going for a while.

How do gallery apps deal with this? they have hundreds of pictures loaded, depending on how many images you have on your phone.

Sure, you can compress the  bitmap and make it smaller in size,  but eventually you will still go oom, right?

Comment: Simple don't load multiple images without thought, you think your phone/tablet has infinite memory ? load, change density, store, free, move on...I love people who ask a question and then immediately disappear... as if they are saying fix this for me... I have a life ....I will reply when I'm ready ! Stay **ONLINE** we respond fast here !

Comment: I love people that ask an incomplete question and disappear. Are you using Fragments for each step? Are you using Activities? What are you doing? WHAT ARE YOU DOING, Stefan, where are you? SHOW US!

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Is he still not here??

Comment: @LieForBananas NOPE.

Comment: I actually was here yesterday, i saw Jon Goodwin's comment, i just didn't reply because i didn't like his attitude. I said i stored images either from camera or from picking one into an imageview, and that doing that multiple times with multilpe image views caused OOM. I also asked a question because i wonder how gallery apps do this, but i didn't get a respond from that either. instead he just bashed me. so no. i didnt feel like replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations in Android methods. I predict that you have passed the image from camera to another activity or view.

This is because you can't send data more than 1 mb in putExtra() method.

Now a days size of camera image extends 5mb in Android mobiles, you can't use them without compressing.  [Here](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) is good image compressor which i use for years.

Use this compressing for camera or gallery before further processing that image.

Comment: That's an interesting compressor. I do still wonder though, how do gallery apps load hundreds of pictures? When you scroll down, it will load them, and when you scroll back up, they're still loaded and don't have to be reloaded.

Hypothetically, if i were to keep adding images, would i go out of memory? This is not a scenario that will happen, but i still wonder nontheless

Comment: They use image loading libraries like Piccaso : https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: use this library to load your image ,it will handle thousands of images itself.

Comment: i'm also using picasso

Comment: Then don't worry, Picasso does it's best :). You just use compressed image,

Comment: Compress at level which you actually need.

Comment: Yeah, i'm going to combine the compressing with picasso. Should be more than enough

Comment: Do you realize that compressing the image loses quality. So how do apps that take real photos deal with this? You take the photo, you store the “Raw” file to disk, you pass a reference (name? key?) to find that file later to another activity, that other activity/fragment will pick it up, in full size, and create a thumbnail (smaller, way smaller) for preview/display in a small canvas until the user wants to export/see the FULL image, then you load only THAT full image. Compressing the image is just adding a if (!null) check just because you saw a NPE, find the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Compressing reduce quality yes! But when we need 4k image?
Original images are never needed. You can not feel quality difference between original and compressed when using in web and app. So we can go along with compressed image. Did you try tinycompress website that gives you compressed image without losing quality?